# PostGIS - Intersects feature to split into linestring

Tags: postgis, postgresql, intersection, linestring

I would like to know if it's possible to intersect feature datasets (multipolygon, polygon, multilinestring and linestring) to get a result as a set of linestrings being split at each intersection point.

[image]

Output should give:

- 4 linestrings for the square
- 3 linestrings for the line
- 2 linestrings for the polygon

Comment: [ST_Intersection][1]
[1]: http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_Intersection.html

Comment: To clarify, are you interested solely in the line portions of the features that fall inside the square, or do you want all possible intersections?  The former would equal 1 linestring each for the line and polygon.  The latter would equal 1 linestring for the line feature, and 2 for the overlapping polygon features.  Also, what is your desired use for the result?  Do you wish to be able to relate back to the original features?

Comment: @GetSpatial - I am looking for all possible intersections in order to be able to reconstruct the original features from the output linestrings later. See edit for number of linestrings needed in output

Comment: Just to be sure I'm reading this correctly.  You want to be able to reconstruct the original features, so you are going to want to maintain some identity of which features the parts belonged to.  That changes the functions you will want to use.

Comment: @GetSpatial, yes, so I suppose I have to add a field that will contains the original feature Id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, for polygons, you want the outer boundary of the polygon as a line using [`ST_Boundary`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Boundary.html).
Then you want a combination of [`ST_Intersection`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersection.html) and [`ST_SymDifference`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_SymDifference.html)

So something like (untested):

```
WITH firststep AS( SELECT id, ST_BOUNDARY(geom) AS boundary
FROM polygons)

SELECT p.id, ST_Intersection(boundary, geom), o.id
FROM firststep p
INNER JOIN othergeoms o ON ST_INTERSECTS(boundary, geom)

UNION

SELECT p.id, ST_SymDifference(boundary, geom), o.id
FROM firststep p
INNER JOIN othergeoms o ON ST_INTERSECTS(boundary, geom)
```